# Forcing evaluation across an IORef: rnf, deepSeq, or something else?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ioref

I have a long-running process which is `forkIO`'d, which produces pixel color values:

```
takesAgesToRun :: [[Color]]

myForkedProcess :: IORef [[Color]] -> IO ()
myForkedProcess ref = do let colors = takesAgesToRun
                         writeIORef ref colors
```

(where `Color` just holds three `Double` values).

As expected, when read on the "other side" of the `IORef`, the value that was stored is just a thunk, and hence blocks the main process.

I know I need to fully evaluate the `[[Color]]` value to head normal form, but there seem to be two ways of achieving that, and further, I'm not sure how to incorporate either into my code.

**How would I go about this? Do I use `rnf`, `deepSeq`, or some other threading strategy?** Is one of these the preferred one, and the others deprecated? And how does it fit into my code?

(PS please ignore the fact that storing the image as a list of a list of colors is stupid - this is just a simplified version of the code).

Comment: Note that if you use [[Color]] to presents pixels the performance of your program is likely to be abysmal no matter how much you parallelize it.

Comment: @tibbe - yep, agreed. I'm very much new to Haskell, so beyond getting the program actually working, my next aim is to keep the UI of the application responding. I'll be moving the bitmap storage to a `UArray` or similar later - but I'll still need this functionality either way.

Comment: Also consider unboxed vectors from the vector library. I've been messing with those and they seemed better designed as well as being more performant ;)

Comment: @stusmith - although the principles behind your decision are sensible, I would recommend that you move to an alternative storage implementation sooner rather than later.  Since lists have different structure from arrays and vectors, you won't be able to accurately gauge your algorithms.  Either you'll write algorithms meant to use an array and get horrible performance with lists, or you'll write algorithms tuned for lists with sub-optimal results on other structures. It'll also make interfacing with other libraries simpler, provided you use compatible storage.

Comment: @monadic: I've never seen unboxed vectors have better performance than arrays, could you post an example somewhere?  I don't think there's any question the interface is much richer though.

Comment: @John L I thought they had better stream fusion... Maybe its the boxed vectors that are better, but according to some benchmark I saw, vectors were better. If I do have one complaint, though, it has to be the lack of an NFData instance. Apparently its because vector is a boot library for ghc but deepseq is not, so they won't add the dependency until ghc 7.2. Anyway, I'm setting up a quick criterion test right now ;)

Comment: @John L Okay, it seems that for mutable, vectors are slightly better than array in a simple test benchmark where each element is set to its index. For immutable, vectors are actually slightly worse.

Comment: @monadic: that makes sense; I don't think arrays do any fusion.  So if you write code which depends upon it arrays will suffer.  I haven't run into it myself because the array interface doesn't particularly lend itself to pipelining functions anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `deepSeq`.  It's used just like `seq`.  You would incorporate it like this:

```
myForkedProcess :: IORef [[Color]] -> IO ()
myForkedProcess ref = do let colors = takesAgesToRun
                         deepSeq colors $ writeIORef ref colors
```

This will force "colors" to be fully evaluated before the "writeIORef" call.

In order for this to work, you will need an `NFData` instance for `Color`.  Exactly how to write this depends upon the definition of Color, but here are two examples:

```
-- just for reference
data Color = Color Double Double Double

instance NFData Color where
    rnf (Color r g b) = r `seq` g `seq` b `seq` ()

-- closer to the likely actual implementation for Color
data Color2 = Color2 !Double !Double !Double

instance NFData  Color2 where
-- the default implementation is fine
```

For the `Color` instance, you need to ensure that all components of the color are fully evaluated[1] whenever Color is.  That's what the `seq`s do.  We can use `seq` instead of `deepSeq` here because we know that each component is a `Double`, therefore is fully evaluated by seq.  If a component were a more complex data type, then we would need to use `deepSeq` when writing the NFData instance.

In `Color2` it's a bit simpler.  Because of the bang patterns, we know that the components are fully evaluated when `Color2` is.  This means we can use the default implementation, which evaluates `Color2` to weak head normal form, which due to the bang patterns is fully evaluated.

`rnf` is mainly useful when used in combination with Control.Parallel.Strategies.  Here's the current definition of `deepSeq`

```
deepseq :: NFData a => a -> b -> b
deepseq a b = rnf a `seq` b
```

All deepseq does is call `rnf` and guarantee that its output () is evaluated.  This is really the only way to use `rnf` directly.

[1]  Haskell provides only two general ways to evaluate stuff: pattern matching and `seq`.  Everything else is built upon one or both of these.  For the NFData Color instance, `Color` is first evaluated to WHNF by pattern matching with the `Color` constructor, then the components are evaluated via seq.

Of course there is also a third, highly specialized, way to evaluate stuff: i.e. a function  `main :: IO ()` will be executed in order to evaluate the `()`.

Comment: Many thanks! This might all seem obvious stuff to some, but searching the web finds a lot of discussion of this sort of thing, but not how it actually applies to real code (or at least, not much that my limited ability can comprehend). Maybe someday there'll be a volume II to "Learn You a Haskell...".

Comment: Forgot to mention this before, but if you're forking processes it's better to use either MVar's or STM instead of IOVar's.  Not all operations on IOVar's are guaranteed to be atomic.